# Plot geographical data python

Tags: python, geopandas

I have data which looks like:

```
OBJECTID,"ID_0","ISO","NAME_0","ID_1","NAME_1","ID_2","NAME_2","TYPE_2","ENGTYPE_2","NL_NAME_2","VARNAME_2"

1,158,"NLD","Netherlands",1,"Drenthe",1,"Aa en Hunze","Gemeente","Municipality",NA,NA

2,158,"NLD","Netherlands",1,"Drenthe",2,"Assen","Gemeente","Municipality",NA,NA
```

etc.

This gives a plot of the Netherlands with the different 'gemeentes'.

Now I have data per gemeente in numbers. So in example:

```
Aa en Hunze: 150

Assen: 125
```

etc.

Can I combine this data with my plot? So for example, the higher te number, the more red the gemeente will be in the plot? Or something equal?

Comment: Check out the folium package which contains a choropleth map option